# Skulpt: Is there any way to import a python module that should be installed via pip 'on skulpt'?

Tags: python, pip, selenium-chromedriver, app-inventor, skulpt

A module that should be installed via `pip` (in my case it is [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)) doesn't work on [skulpt](https://skulpt.org/) (app-inventor).

I'm not a native English speaker. Thanks.

Comment: Try to write a more about your question: what have you tried so far? what is the error you get? etc. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think you can install selenium, which is a browser automation tool, on a browser itself.